# Оптимизация использования отношений на большой выборке данных

Tags: php, laravel

Столкнулся с проблемой при выборке большого количества данных.
Как оказалось Laravel  связывает таблицы через оператор `IN` что не очень хорошо при выборке > 1M `Model::with('user')` получаем что-то вроде `id in (1,2,3, ... 1000000)`

Example: 
Есть таблица пользователей вида `'id', 'name', 'email', 'number', 'bdate'`
У каждого пользователя может быть создано в системе несколько проектов `'id', 'user_id', 'title', 'data', 'price', 'mode'` поле `user_id` индексное

нужно выбрать всех пользователей и их проекты. Пускай модель выглядит так:

```
class User extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'users'

    public function project()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App/Project', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Какие есть варианты обхода ?

Да можно написать запрос самому с пагинацией и обрабатывать данный например по 50 000. Есть ли возможность сделать это средствами laravel при описании связи модели.

Comment: А кастомные `where()` или `join()` использовать не вариант?

Comment: @VenZell да вариант, но возможно есть менее очевидные методы.

Comment: А можете показать конкретный пример, демонстрирующий вашу проблему? Нужен пример структуры таблиц и как вы их связываете в соответствующих моделях.

Comment: Таких выборок быть не должно ни в Laravel нигде, даже с join-ом таблицы милионники соединять - нельзя. Лучше помозговать и переделать выборку, переделать логику. Иначе с этим позже будут проблемы.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр умные слова, но решения проблемы Вы не предлагаете к сожалению. Когда у меня была подобная проблема в Yii2 (схожие фреймверки), я ее решал добавлением полей счетчиков в модель пользователя (например счетчик колиества проэктов). Таким образом для главной страницы мне хватало данных из модели User, а уже при открытии страницы пользователя подтягивались все его проэкты.

Comment: Проблема eager relation pagination имеет место быть, вот более менее понятное объяснение http://stackoverflow.com/a/25127812/5892568

Answer (score 1):

> что не очень хорошо при выборке > 1M Model::with('user') получаем
>   что-то вроде id in (1,2,3, ... 1000000)

Это не нормально, джоинить таблицы-милионники. Надо менять структуры данных/алгоритмы - если такое возникает. Структуру данных под задачу всегда можно подобрать, при чём так, что всё работать будет быстро. Что надо конкретно - не описано, кроме как сджоинить большие таблицы. Поэтому ответ никто и не даёт.

P.S. Топ порталы , например,  фейсбук, вк - при использовании SQL запрещают join  - как раз по этой причине.

> Как оказалось Laravel связывает таблицы через оператор IN

Не хочешь париться и оставить джоин, тоже решение - но тогда зачем пользоваться конструциями Laravel для выборки из ORM, коли они делают выборку с джоинами не так как хочется? Разве там нельзя получить БД-адаптер , вписать выборку с join-ом вручную, получить колонку id-шников, а затем в цикле по ним сформировать объекты юзеров? Думаю можно! Даже думаю можно скормить выборку id-шников объекту-пажинатору, который судя по комменту используется: чтобы он сам проставлял limit/offset или max id/min id.

Думаю можно и в "Репозитории пользователей"(или он может называться класс таблицы пользователей) - добавить метод, который формирует тебе такой список объектов User по твоей выборке. И это архитектурно верно.

P.S. Если в чём-то конкретно не прав, не пеняй - Laravel в глаза не видел. За то более чем видел Zend(1,2,3), Yii